# Seminorm continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, locally-convex-spaces

I am reading functional analysis from an applied math textbook and I have to admit some of the exercises confuse me, in the sense I am not sure what is asked of me.

"Show that each of the seminorms inducing a locally convex topology is continuous with respect to this topology"

I tried a naive approach (seminorm p is after all a function from a vector space to R) so $\forall \epsilon >0$, I picked $\delta = \epsilon$ and went ahead with the usual definition of continuity to show that for every $x,y\in V$ $|p(x)-p(y)|< \epsilon$. But I was told this is not correct - I understand that this way I am not using at all that these seminorms are the ones producing a locally convex v.s, but in my mind all seminorms are continuous (maybe I am missing the "with respect to this topology part").

The next approach I tried (which I am not confident of) is by assuming that the sets in my textbook associated with the norms that induce a locally convex space are $B(I_o,\epsilon) = \{v\in V :p_i(u)\leq \epsilon , \forall i\in I\}$. These are neighborhoods of zero and addition and multiplication are continuous operations because of the seminorm homogeneity and triangle inequality properties.

I also tried to use that $f$ is continuous at $x$ iff $f(B_x)\succ B_{f(x)}$ but I failed.

Could you help me realize what I need to do and how I do it to answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_0\in X$ and $\epsilon> 0$ be given. Then set $U := \{x\in X : p(x-x_0) < \epsilon\}$. As a subbasis element of the locally convex topology, this set is open in $X$ and for all $x\in U$ you have $|p(x)-p(x_0)|\le p(x-x_0) < \epsilon$.

Comment: I've seen this set (online) before when trying to understand the question, but why\how did you pick it? I saw that in other textbooks this one is used wtrt seminorms inducing a locally convex topological space, but it's not in my book, so could you explain your thought process? Edit: I just saw your edit which explains that, thanks.

Comment: @Iniciador I'm afraid this is just experience. I cannot give you a special reason for how I picked this. I guess I just remembered it from somewhere deep down in my retarded brain. ;-)

Comment: I am afraid I know what you mean ;-) Thanks though !